# What is the concise word or phrase of getting caught in an embarrassing situation?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> I got caught in an embarrasing situation last night! I was singing until I realise I'd been being watched by my neighbour.

In my view, I won't consider it natural to say that since it's too wordy. I also tried to google that phrase and found this one from macmillan dictionary :

> **be/get caught (up) in something**
>
> DEFINITION
>
> 1 to become unexpectedly involved in
> an unpleasant or annoying situation
>
> - We were caught in a heavy storm.

Trying to rephrase my sentence like this:

> I got caught singing by my neighbour last night and it was embarrasing!

However, from the definition above, I don't think I have used the phrase "to get caught" correctly. Is there any natural way to say this? To be precise, I don't know whether my sentence is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, "[be/get caught in an embarrassing situation](https://ludwig.guru/s/caught+in+an+embarrassing)" is a quite common expression and probably the most common one. _Moment_ can be used instead of _situation_ also. There can be other words/word groups  used instead of _situation_ like _position, lie_ etc. in other contexts.

Comment: I **realised** I **was** being watched by my neighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if there is an alternative for this phrase, but "get caught in an embarrassing situation" is already a common phrase used. Depending on your context, you can even say:

> get caught in an embarrassing moment - @ermanen

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is correct but it doesn't use the idiom you quoted. You're using *catch* in the sense of [discover someone in the act](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/catch_1#catch_1__31). In the context, "it was embarrassing" is implied because this sense of the verb is overwhelming used with actions that are "wrong" in some sense (and it's not like your singing is illegal).

As an alternative: You were singing until you realized you **made a fool of yourself** in front of your neighbor. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20a%20fool%20of%20oneself):

> to behave in a very foolish or silly way
>
> - He got drunk at the party and made a fool of himself.
> - He's making a fool of himself over that woman.